# leak when scrolling html in web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm seeing a memory leak that i'm not sure what's the source of it:
i have a simple UIView that contains simple UIWebview and a method that display it accordingly

```
[self setHelp]; 

NSString *HTMLData = @"<body style='background-color:black;'> <p style='color:white;'> <u style='color:teal;'>  Using xMode</u> <br />There are a number of ways you can customize the program to suit your needs. In its most simplistic way xMode can be used in its easy mode. In this mode (default mode ) you need to enter a gross amount for each applicable category right at the textbox of the button. ...blah blah..................</p>   <br /> <br /> </body>";

[WV loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
```

I have severals html screens and all works fine. However when i test using Instrument
it show a leak ONLY when i scroll the help screen , if i just close/open no scrolling no leaks shows.

any idea what could cause that, is it from my code or from some framework or library?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I didn't get any reply and wonder if the question fell thru the cracks? anyone ?